# c# error while copying arraylist to array

Tags: c#

I have 2 arraylists in my project, list1, and list2. (both contains 9 String values, car1, car2, car3 and so on.

I also have an string array, called store_numbers which can contain 52 String elements.
Now I wanna copy my values from list1 and list2 to the array.
By doing :

```
  list1.CopyTo(store_numbers,0);
```

Which I think is the right way
I get the error message

> At least one element in the source could not be cast down to the
>   destination array type

Anyone who knows how I can Fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the message? Your types are wrong.

Comment: you sure all things in your arraylist are string?

Comment: The error is shouting type mismatch between your arrays; can you post your code (at least the definitions of all arrays concerned)?

Comment: My arraylists contains values like "car1","car2" and so on!

Comment: Make sure they are all strings or better yet, post the exact code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have something close to this:

```
ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList{"car1",2,"car3","car4","car5",
                                "car6","car7","car8","car9"};

string[] store_numbers = new string[] {"10","11","12","13","14","15",
                                       "16","17","18"};

list1.CopyTo(store_numbers,0);
```

The above will throw the following error:

```
 `At least one element in the source array could not be cast 
  down to the destination array type.`
```

There is the number 2 in list1, that is why you get the error in this case.  Change to `List<string>` to avoid this.

Answer (score 12):

You have something in your `ArrayList` that isn't a string.

The best fix is not to use `ArrayList`! It's been obsolete since .NET 2.0 came out. Use a `List<string>` instead. Then the compiler will prevent you from putting a non-string in the list in the first place, and your copy should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My arraylists contains values like "car1","car2" and so on!

Answer (score 1):

Are you really sure that the arraylists only contain strings? The error message indicates that at least one object in one of the arraylists isn't a string. If you set a breakpoint at the place where the problem occurs you should be able to look at the arraylist contents.

Also you shouldn't be using `ArrayList` at all - it is deprecated. Use `List<String>` to get type safety.

Comment: Thanks for answer! My arraylists contains values like "car1","car2" and so on!

Answer (score 0):

make sure all items in your `ArrayList` have the same datatype.if not, you have to convert all items to string before copying it.